# Ionic : $ ionic run android shows path error, not running the application on mobile

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have developed one mobile app using cordova and ionic framework. I want to test that app in my mobile but when i tried the following command
      `$ ionic run android` it showed me following error:

```
$ ionic run android
Error { [Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\work\hooks']
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
path: 'C:\\Users\\work\\hooks',
syscall: 'scandir' }
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
```

How to resolve that one?
    link of the documentation is [Here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project,.

Project structure is like that

```
project <==== from here you shall start command
  -> hooks
  -> www
  -> ..
```

as from your logs, maybe your project is here path: 'C:\Users\work\

Comment: Actually, he's probably invoking command in that dir. And it contains no ionic project.

Comment: my project is n the c:/xampp/htdocs/myProject/module_based/index.php then what to do in my case?

Comment: your project does not seems to be a ionic base project.  http://ionicframework.com/docs/concepts/structure.html